# Delete all scheduled tasks with Registry file

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, windows-task-scheduler, telemetry

There are many scheduled task including all of which are associated with TELEMETRY and user data collection in Windows 10. One can find those scheduled task in Task Scheduler Management Console (taskschd.msc). Is there a way to delete/remove them all permanently with registry file at once?

Comment: Did you actually performed all tasks removal? Have you noticed any downsides afterwards?

Comment: @Rayearth No issue in my case. It depends if you're dependent upon those tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following process works in my machine Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

- Scheduled tasks are stored in this registry **`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule]`**. Backup/export this whole `Schedule` registry key.
- Delete the whole `Schedule` registry key by adding this line in a new .reg file `[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule]`. And also delete "%SystemRoot%\System32\Tasks" and "%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\Tasks" (only for 64bit OS) with takeown and icacls command.
- But deleting that registry key task scheduler and Defragment shows an error.
  [image: Task Schedular error][image: Defragment error]
- Copy the **`SD`** reg_binary value of the path `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree]` from that previous backup in this new registry file. This solves the task scheduler error.
- Also add this line `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\Microsoft\Windows\Defrag\ScheduledDefrag]` to solve the defragment error. Here is the whole registry file::

[image: Registry File]

Alternatively, with command `SchTasks /Delete /TN * /F`

See also:: [Is there a way to quickly delete/disable ALL scheduled Tasks?](https://superuser.com/questions/1010985/is-there-a-way-to-quickly-delete-disable-all-scheduled-tasks)